# How do I program different stages of a game?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I'm creating a mobile game that that has two parts. The first is slow, the second is fast. The second executes after the first has been satisfied.

I was thinking of running the game in a game loop and separating the two stages in the loop:

```
MainGameLoop:
while (running) {
 while (!FirstStage.isDone) {
  FirstStage.run(); 
 }
 while (!SecondStage.isDone) {
  SecondStage.run();
 }
}
```

Is this the correct paradigm? Are there any established game programming paradigm/patterns I can consult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to go with games is using "State Machines".   Very easy to work with and to extend.

```
while(true)
{
    switch(game_state)
    {  
       case SLOW_STUFF: // whatver
             if(move_on):  game_state = FAST_STUFF; // or something like this.
             break;
       case FAST_STUFF:  // whatever..
       // then also...
       case GAME_OVER:
       case WAIT_FOR_START:
       case QUIT:
          // save state..
          return;
     etc

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it's correct. But in practice, your app will be event-driven, and will probably not have it's own loop, but utilize the system's event loop, such as on Android.
This is often implicit.
So at the completion of the first stage, an event will be fired (a method will be called), which sets a state indicating the second stage is running.